# JavaScript code in library.js executing at onLoad event

Tags: javascript

In all the research I've done, I am under the impression function calls in 'scr' files is not executed until called in the  of the DOM.  But this does not seem to be true.

My example:

```
<title id="pageTitle">Investment(s)
</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/library.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/investment.js">
</script>
```

...any function in either 'src' file with an alert() statement, shows up at onLoad().  Is this normal?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

`<script>` tags cause the browser to stop what it is doing and begin downloading/executing the script immediately. They do not wait for the dom to finish loading before they run. [Read more](http://www.sitepoint.com/a-detailed-breakdown-of-the-script-tag/).